# Apex class and trigger to update Child object field

Tags: trigger

I am trying to update the child object - `Vacancy_D2D__c` field name-`Worksite_Location__c` with parent object `TR1__Job__c` field `TR1__Account__r.Name`.

below is helper class.

Comment: Hi All. 

I am trying to update the child object - Vacancy_D2D__c field name-"Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c " with parent object TR1__Job__c field "TR1__Account__r.Name". But unable to do it. below is helper class. plz help.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can you share the error your getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. Trigger and class is saving but Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c field value is not updating

Comment: @Sohel I think you should use vacancyD2D.Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c == null instead of Vacancy_D2D__c.Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c == null in your if condition.

Answer (score 1):

In the If condition of your helper class you should check null value with the reference of instance (vacancyD2D) of the `object` Vacancy_D2D__c-

```java
public void setAccountName(List<Vacancy_D2D__c> vacancySchedules){
    Set<String> vSetVacId = new Set<String>();
    for (Vacancy_D2D__c vacancyD2D : vacancySchedules) {
        vSetVacId.add(vacancyD2D.Vacancy__c);
    }
    Map< Id, TR1__Job__c> vMapTRIdTR = new Map<Id, TR1__Job__c>();
    vMapTRIdTR.putAll([SELECT Id, TR1__Account__r.Name FROM TR1__Job__c WHERE Id In :vSetVacId]);
    for (Vacancy_D2D__c vacancyD2D : vacancySchedules) {
        if (vacancyD2D.Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c == null && vMapTRIdTR.containskey(vacancyD2D.Vacancy__c)) {
            vacancyD2D.Work_Shift_Location_lkId__c = vMapTRIdTR.get(vacancyD2D.Vacancy__c).TR1__Account__r.Name ;
        }
    }
}
```